# some apps, no problem loading on 2 devices. Not this one - help

Tags: applications, amazon-kindle-fire, amazon-appstore, multiple-devices

I have loaded a free app (imediashare) from Amazon store onto my Kindle Fire. I want to put the same app on my Samsung phone, but when I go to the app store from the phone and try to 'buy' it, I'm told I already own it.

I have had no trouble doing this same action with some other apps, nor with any books (putting them on both devices)

I think I may be able to reload it from my apps library, but I cannot find it, navigating from the Samsung.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This article should help:

[How to install paid apps on multiple Android devices](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20100093-285/how-to-install-paid-apps-on-multiple-android-devices/)

Also you can try to install application using [web version of Play Store](https://play.google.com/) (in the `Send to` list select needed device, for example, your phone).